# Why doesn't this_thread::sleep_for need to be linked against pthread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, sleep

Usually when building thread related code in GCC, explicit linking against pthread is necessary:

```sh
g++ -pthread main.cxx
```

However, the following code compiles, links, and runs fine without being linked against pthread:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    return 0;
}
```

I guess what is happening here is that `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is using some POSIX function from libc (instead of something from pthread)? But if that is the case, does the execution of `std::this_thread::sleep_for` change depending on whether or not it was called from the main thread?

Comment: since C++11 threads are part of the language and any interaction with the OS is handled for you (I haven't used pthreads or OS specific API's for threading since). sleep_for will always suspend the thread it is called on. So your call from main will suspend the mainthread for 1 second. (On a side note : if you want to use threads from C++ have a look at std::async)

Comment: See "Why glibc 2.34 removed libpthread" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414930/why-does-gcc-require-lpthread-to-link-against-pthread-functions-but-doesnt-r

Comment: @PepijnKramer -- the question is about the g++ quirk that you have to (had to?) explicitly link to the pthreads library when using C++ threads.

Comment: @PeteBecker My apologies, I wasn't aware of that quirk. (mostly using msvc compiler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't this_thread::sleep_for need to be linked against pthread?

Because the call to `std::this_thread::sleep_for` translates into underlying call to `nanosleep`, which is defined in `libc.so.6`, and not in `libpthread.so.0`.

Note that when linking with GLIBC-2.34 and later, using other functions (which previously required `-pthread`) no longer require it, because [GLIBC got rid of `libpthread`](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/12/17/why-glibc-234-removed-libpthread).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414930/why-does-gcc-require-lpthread-to-link-against-pthread-functions-but-doesnt-r).

Comment: The `-pthread` option is not only about linking `libpthread` (else `-lpthread` would have sufficed).  It's not clear to me yet whether glibc's removal of a separate `libpthread` will be matched by GCC deprecating its `-pthread` option.  The latest (11.2) GCC manual does not deprecate it, and it has long been documented as both a preprocessing option and a linker option.